# windows is not defined

Tags: javascript, serverside-javascript, server-side-rendering

I am trying to do some server side rendering in my React app, the problem is that I use packages like `vivus` or `react-inlinesvg` and they use the `window` variable inside them, and all I get is the error of `window is not defined`. Is there any way to overcome this problem?

Comment: I also do server side rendering and not using packages that is not compatible with node.js environment. I have my own component for rendering svgs. I don't know what vivus is but i am sure there is another package for that or you can write your own. 

Comment: Vivus is used for animation of svg drawing. 
Going to see if there are any other libraries out there.

Comment: I have used [animejs](https://github.com/juliangarnier/anime) ones. It has no problem with server side rendering as i can remember.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? If not, could you share your code.

Comment: No solution – but these days plenty of libraries should support server-side rendering if you want to pursue this. If not, libraries like prerender.io can save tons of development hours.